# PowerShell command "test-netconnection <address> -p <port number>" fails with any port

Tags: windows-10, port

[Articles like this one][1] and [this one][2] show how to use Telnet or PowerShell to test if a port is open. When I try, both methods fail (time out), not only with special ports that I have opened in Windows firewall but with port 80, which should work -- right?  What am I missing?

Here's the PowerShell approach:

```
test-netconnection <address> -p <port number>
```

The resulting output is:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> test-netconnection 192.168.1.107 -p 80
WARNING: TCP connect to (192.168.1.107 : 80) failed


ComputerName           : 192.168.1.107
RemoteAddress          : 192.168.1.107
RemotePort             : 80
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet 2
SourceAddress          : 192.168.1.105
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False



PS C:\Windows\system32> ping 192.168.1.107

Pinging 192.168.1.107 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.107: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.107: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
```

Comment: Please [edit] the article links into your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, port 80 shouldn't just work by default, unless you have an HTTP (insecure) web server running.

> `PingSucceeded          : True`

This line shows that the tnc output agrees with your ping command. You simply don't have port 80 open on your .107 host. A successful ICMP ping doesn't imply that a TCP port is open.

Your `test-netconnection` command is working as expected. If you want to test an open port, try some of the common ones: 135, 443, 445, 3389 etc.